# Underscore JS extend object with non-null values from new object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, extend

I would like to do something like...

```
_.extend(original, fresh);
```

But only to copy over attributes that are not null, so...

```
var original = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
var fresh = {a:5, b:null}

var mixed = _.extend(original, fresh)
// currently mixed is {a:5,b:null,c:3}
// I want it to be {a:5,b:2,c:3}
```

---

### Updates

I made some progress, but it does not work with nested objects...

http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/2GwMx/1/

```
var original = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:{g:1}}
var fresh = {a:5, b:null,c:"", d:{e:4,f:5,g:null}}

var mixed = _.extend( original, _.reduce(fresh,function(a,v,k){ 
     if(v){ a[k]=v; } 
     return a; 
}, {}) )

// currently mixed is {"a":5,"b":2,"c":3,"d":{"e":4,"f":5,"g":null}}
// I want it to be {"a":5,"b":2,"c":3,"d":{"e":4,"f":5,g:1}}
alert(JSON.stringify(mixed))
```

Comment: How are you getting that `fresh` object, is there any possibility to simply omit those `null` properties (by `delete`ing them)?

Comment: fresh is json returned from the server. I must modify it in JS after I receive it.

Comment: In your update you probably want to use `!= null` so falsy items arent excluded (eg 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A touch of javascript with a dash of underscore:

```
_.mixin({
  extendNonNull: function(obj) {
    _.each(_.rest(arguments,1), function(source) {
      if (source) {
        for (var prop in source) {
          if( _.isObject(source[prop]) && _.isObject(obj[prop])){
             obj[prop] = _.extendNonNull(obj[prop], source[prop]);
          }
          else if( !_.isNull(source[prop])){
             obj[prop] = source[prop];
          }
        }
      }
    });
    return obj;
  }
});

var original = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:{g:1}};
var fresh = {a:5, b:null,c:"", d:{e:4,f:5,g:null}};

var mixed = _.extendNonNull(original, fresh);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using lodash or underscore, this is how you can do:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
let result = _.merge({},target, source);
let clonedNonNull = _.omit(result,_.isNull);
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly right - in my example, the original value of `b` needs to be carried forwards, not stripped out.

Comment: did u try it. the merge should get all a, b,c in the result. and the omit should then trim off all the nulls and undefined

Comment: I didn't try it, does not appear to be underscore function _.merge - perhaps a lodash specific thing..?

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash you can pass a filter function as last parameter of the **assignWith**  function.
Then you can filter the **null** values or more specific cases and merge more than 2 objects at the same time.

```
let obj1 = {a: 'foo', b: null}
let obj2 = {a: null, b: 'bar'}

// acc is the accumulator value
function filter(acc, newValue) {
  let isNull = _.isNull(newValue);
  return isNull ? acc : newValue;
}

let mixin = _.assignWith({}, obj1, obj2, filter); // {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}
```

Comment: Neat, but I don’t think this handles nested properties does it?

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately, it's just an alternative syntax using lodash.